# Proof $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ for $a_{n+1} \geq qa_n$

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_n > 0$ for all  $n \in \mathbb{N}, q >1, N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$a_{n+1} \geq qa_n$$

for all $n \geq N_0$.

How can one prove that the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ diverges towards $+\infty$?

I know that the proof for $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ for $a_{n+1} \leq qa_n$ is the following:

Fix $N_{0}$ and $q\in\left[0,1\right)$. For $n= N_{0}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ you have $a_{n+k}\leq q a_{n+k-1}\leq q^{2}a_{n+k-2}\leq\dots q^{k}a_{n}$.

\begin{align}
0\leq \lim_{m\to\infty}a_{m}=\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n+k}\leq a_{n}\lim_{k\to\infty}q^{k}=0
\end{align}

Is there a similar proof for $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ for $a_{n+1} \geq qa_n$?

Comment: Come on, $a_n\ge q^na_0$ !

Comment: Have you tried to adapt this proof? It would should work with the necessary adaptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b _n=\frac  1{a_n}$ and $q'=\frac  1 q$ Then $ q' \in [0,1)$ and $b_{n+1} \leq b_n q'$ so $b_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Well since every $a_n > 0$ you have $a_0 > 0$ and therefore

$$a_n \geq q^n a_0$$

Since $q>1$ you know that $q^n \to \infty$. This leads you to $a_n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$a_{n+1}\ge qa_n\ge q^2 a_{n-1}\ge ... \ge q^na_1$

Now as $n\to +\infty$ then $a_n \to +\infty$ since $q>1$

Answer (score 2):

In context , this proof involves a few basics, perhaps a nice exercise.

$a_n \ge qa_0 >0$ is an increasing sequence, bounded below by $qa_0 >0$;

$a_{n+1} \ge qa_n  \in \mathbb{N}$.

Assume a limit $L >0$, real,  exists, then

$L= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} \ge \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}qa_{n+1} =qL$,

We have

$L \ge qL$, $q>1$, a contradiction.

Hence $a_n$ is not bounded from above.

(If it were a limit would exist (Why?))

Since $a_n   >0$ is increasing, and not bounded from above

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=\infty$.